# What is an effective way to organize C++ projects that are going to be unit tested?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-organization

I am wondering what would be an effective way to organize C++ projects and classes that are going to be unit tested. I have read many SO posts related to unit test but couldn't find practical examples.

Here are some ways I have collected:

**Method A**

- **Project A**: Application (.exe) project that "include" the classes from Project C
- **Project B**: Unit test (.exe) project that "include" the classes from Project C
- **Project C**: Static library (.lib) project that keeps all classes that Project A uses

**Method B**

- **Project A**: Application (.exe) project with all classes inside itself.
- **Project B**: Unit test (.exe) project that "links" to classes in Project A

**Method C** (from Miguel)

- only one project, with three configurations:

  - Debug: builds your Application .exe in debug mode.
  - Release: builds your Application .exe in release mode.
  - Test: builds the unit test framework, replaces your app's main() with the unit testing main()

Which is the more appropriate way? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have previously used the first method quite well. Have most of your code in a static library project, have the main executable project just contain the main function, and have your tests and the test main function in a third project. The two executable projects will link to the static library and reuse the code.

The main benefits in doing it this way are:

- The code that is being tested is the exact same build as is used in your application.
- You can test both the debug and release configurations to ensure that both work as expected. (You can extrapolate debug and release for any configurations that you might require.)
- Build time is minimised since the same built library is used in both executable projects.
- Can have the build system build both the test and main executable at the same time, and also run the test executable after building.

Answer (score 2):

There's not that much difference actually, as you can always compile the exe as a static library and link against the unit tests. Conceptually, Method A is slightly cleaner, but there's nothing preventing you from using Method B. It basically boils down to your build system what is easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll gain much by moving the classes of your application to a static library. You should also consider that you may want to modify your classes when you compile them for testing, for example by adding additional convenience methods that are not necessary for the application, so in the end putting the classes in a library may not help at all since you will need a special version of these classes when running tests.

I would like to suggest the following as a better option than your methods A and B:

**METHOD C**

- only one project, with three configurations:

  - Debug: builds your Application .exe in debug mode.
  - Release: builds your Application .exe in release mode.
  - Test: builds the unit test framework, replaces your app's main() with the unit testing main()

If you think you need to, you can split the Test target into Debug and Release as well.

Comment: Thanks, Method C would mean I have to: 1. Surround unit tests with **#ifdef TEST_BUILD ... #endif**. 2. Surround application code with **#ifndef TEST_BUILD ... #endif**. Right? Can I add this method to the question?

Comment: Instead of #ifdef'ing I would just have two source files, once with the application's main() and another one with the unit test main(). You compile the correct one on each configuration. And yes, feel free to update your question with my suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way since you will either need to select which (debug/release) configuration you want your test config to follow, or create two test configurations, one for debug and one for release.

Comment: What's wrong with having two configs Test/Debug and Test/Release? This is exactly the same if you use any of the other approaches suggested.

Comment: My main beef is that you'd need to keep 2 configurations in sync with their parent ones, adding/removing & enabling/disabling files, and it would get quite complicated. Having separate projects means the configuration can be a lot simpler. Also it is conceptually simpler to have separate test projects rather than the same project emitting different things based on different configurations.